# INDY 10 SSL RootCertFile gives garbage address

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy

I am using C++ Builder 10.3 with the Indy 10 component IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

If I set just the ClientCert to my host CA cert, I can connect TLS fine.

```
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->CertFile     = net->clientname;
```

However, if I try to set the root certificate I get a file not found error which is the path to my executable with a chinese string for the file name.

net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->RootCertFile = net->certname;

[image: The exception seen]

As long as I leave the RootCertFile string empty it works, however I wish to add a client certificate for the host to verify which means I need to also put the CA cert into the Root certificate file.

Full intialisation:

```
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->Mode        = sslmClient;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->Host = net->hostname;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->Port = net->port;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->DHParamsFile = "";
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->VerifyDirs   = "";
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->CipherList   = "";
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->CertFile     = net->clientname;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->KeyFile      = net->keyname;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->RootCertFile = net->certname;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->Method      = sslvTLSv1_2;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->VerifyMode  = TIdSSLVerifyModeSet(sslvrfClientOnce);
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->SSLOptions->VerifyDepth = 10;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->OnVerifyPeer            = MainForm->VerifyCertFile;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->ReadTimeout = 10000;
net->IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL->Open();
```

Any suggestions why I get this strange filename exception?

Comment: You're gonna have to show more code than this. It looks like you're probably mishandling memory somewhere.

Comment: @paddy that is not necessary in this case. The corruption is actually on Embarcadero's part this time, not the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I try to set the root certificate I get a file not found error which is the path to my executable with a chinese string for the file name.

That is due to a bug that Embarcadero introduced into Indy in the initial 10.3 release. That bug was fixed with this patch:

[RAD Studio 10.3.3 Indy Server SSL Certificate Patch](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-10-3-3-indy-server-ssl-certificate-patch/)

Or, you can upgrade your IDE to the latest code from Indy's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy), as it never had this bug in it to begin with.

However, you should make sure you have all of the 10.3 patches installed in general:

[RAD Studio, Delphi and C++Builder 10.3.3: List of Patches](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-delphi-and-c-builder-10-3-3-list-of-patches/)

Comment: Thanks Remy, I tried the patch, still got the same error.  Switched my whole project to Rad Studio 10.4 and now no matter which certificate I load, the TLS get rejected by our server.  I have confirmed that I have the correct OpenSSL DLLs.

Comment: @BarryAndrews "*the TLS get rejected by our server*" - rejected how, exactly? What are the details? "*I have confirmed that I have the correct OpenSSL DLLs*" - are you sure? Which DLLs are you using exactly?